# How to write move so that it can potentially be optimized away?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, move

Given the following code:

```
struct obj {
    int i;
    obj() : i(1) {}
    obj(obj &&other) : i(other.i) {}
};

void f() {
    obj o2(obj(obj(obj{})));
}
```

I expect release builds to only really create one object and never call a move constructor because the result is the same **as if** my code was executed. Most code is not that simple though, I can think of a few hard to predict side effects that could stop the optimizer from proving the "as if":

1. changes to global or "outside" things in either the move constructor or destructor.
2. potential exceptions in the move constructor or destructor (probably bad design anyway)
3. internal counting or caching mechanisms changing.

Since I don't use any of these often can I expect most of my moves in and out of functions which are later inlined to be optimized away or am I forgetting something?

P.S. I know that just because an optimization is possible does not mean it will be made by any given compiler.

Comment: Instead of hoping for `as-if` eliminations, you could get rid of the `std::move` calls, and copy-elision will probably remove every single copy/move in that code (even if those move operations have side effects). (`as-if` eliminations would probably just remove `o` from the program entirely).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with the as-if rule. The compiler is allowed to elide moves and copies even if they have some side effect. It is the single optimization that a compiler is allowed to do that might change the result of your program. From §12.8/31:

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the copy/move constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects.

So the compiler doesn't have to bother inspecting what happens inside your move constructor, it will likely get rid of any moves here anyway. To demonstrate this, consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct bad_mover
{
  static int move_count;
  bad_mover() = default;
  bad_mover(bad_mover&& other) { move_count++; }
};

int bad_mover::move_count = 0;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  bad_mover b{bad_mover(bad_mover(bad_mover()))};
  std::cout << "Move count: " << bad_mover::move_count << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

1. Compiled with `g++ -std=c++0x`:

   ```
   Move count: 0
   ```
2. Compiled with `g++ -std=c++0x -fno-elide-constructors`:

   ```
   Move count: 3
   ```

However, I would question any reason you have for providing a move constructor that has additional side effects. The idea in allowing this optimization regardless of side effects is that a copy or move constructor *shouldn't* do anything other than copy or move. The program with the copy or move should be exactly the same as without.

Nonetheless, your calls to `std::move` are unnecessary. `std::move` is used to change an lvalue expression to an rvalue expression, but an expression that creates a temporary object is already an rvalue expression.

Comment: wow, so if i write code that moves an object 10 times and counts in the move constructor I could get a value smaller than 10? That is good to know!

Comment: +1. For the record, this is quoted from §12.8/31, and the "certain criteria" do indeed include the initialization situation of your move constructor.

Comment: @PorkyBrain I added an example that demonstrates that.

Answer (score 2):

Using `std::move( tmp(...) )` is completely pointless, the temporary `tmp` is already an rvalue, you don't need to use `std::move` to cast it to an rvalue.

Read this series of articles: [Want Speed? Pass By Value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)

You'll learn more and understand better than you will by asking a question on Stackoverflow

Comment: yeah your right, I removed the std::move, bad example on my part, my question about side effects remains though.

Comment: The compiler is free to completely ignore side effects when eliding copies or moves. If an initialization is eligible for elision then the compiler can do so, without caring about side effects, possible exceptions or anything else. I've fixed your code so it compiles, and when I run it `o2.i` is `1`. Read the article I linked to and sftrabbit's answer

Comment: `std::move(other.i)` is also completely pointless, `int` has no resources to move so a move is just a copy anyway